# XMLHttpRequest contains non-empty response but XMLHttpRequest.response is <emptystring>

Tags: javascript, debugging, xmlhttprequest

I'm sending HTTP requests and receiving responses with the following code:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
var waiting = true
var sup = this
var userId = userInfo.userId
var userType = 'student'
if (userInfo.type == 2) {
    userType = 'professor'
}
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    try {
        if (this.status == 200 && waiting) {
            waiting = false;
            var courses
            try {
                courses = JSON.parse(xhr.response)
            } catch (jerr) {
                courses = []
            }
            sup.courseArray = courses;
            console.log(sup.courseArray)
            sup.render()
        }
    } catch (err) {}
}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/course/read/' + userType + 'Id/' + userId)
xhr.send()
```

As you can see, I'm only accessing `response` in the callback, so the server has responded and `xhr` has been initialized at that point. If I simply call `console.log(xhr)`, I can clearly see `response` is a non-empty string:

`response: "[{\"id\":1,\"professorId\":1,\"name\":\"java\",\"code\":\"CS1017\"}]"`

However, if I call `console.log(xhr.response)`, I get

`<empty string>`

Does anyone know why I'm seeing this discrepancy?

Comment: Try using JSON.parse(this.response) instead

Answer (score 1):

`this.status == 200` will be true as soon as `xhr.readyState == 2`, but the request will not be completely fulfilled until `xhr.readyState == 4`; at `readyState == 2` `response` will still be empty.

`console.log(xhr)` will eventually show the status at `readyState == 4`, but that's 2 readyStates later than when your code tries to access `xhr.response`.

You have to check that both `status == 200` and `readyState == 4` are `true` to be sure a complete `response` has arrived.

Answer (score 0):

why not try using using JS native fetch instead

```
var waiting = true
var sup = this
var userId = userInfo.userId
var userType = 'student'
if(userInfo.type == 2) {
   userType = 'professor'
}

fetch('http://localhost:8080/course/read/' + userType + 'Id/' + userId)
.then(r => r.json())
.then((response) => {
    waiting = false;
   sup.courseArray = response;
   console.log(sup.courseArray);
   sup.render();
})
.catch((e) => {
     waiting = false;
     console.log(e);
});
```